# Regex match reversed parenthesis in Arabic text

Tags: java, arabic, arabic-support

I'm trying to match a particular pattern in my text which is this:

```
Arabic text ) Arabic Text ( Arabic Text
```

And I'm trying to invert the parentheses to get this:

```
Arabic text ( Arabic Text ) Arabic Text
```

The problem here is the following code couldn't match the part of the text I'm trying to extract this:

```
) Arabic Text (
```

```
private static final Pattern Pat = Pattern.compile("(\\)\\p{InARABIC}*\\()", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

public String replace(String text) {
        Matcher m = Pat.matcher(text);
        while (m.find()) {
            text = m.group(1);
               ++some operations on the extracted text++
             }
}
```

I don't get any match for any of these examples:

```
)أ(
)السلام(
هذا مجرد ) مثال ( .. طبعا
```

I'm expecting this as an output:

```
)أ(
)السلام(
) مثال (
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I even tried unicode range for arabic characters 0600–06FF

Comment: @DevilsHnd it's only for arabic text , i don't want to get the non arabic

Answer (score 3):

Based on

> I'm trying to match a particular pattern in my text which is :
>   Arabic text ) Arabic Text ( Arabic Text
>   and i'm trying to invert the parentheses to get :
>   Arabic text ( Arabic Text ) Arabic Text

It seems that problem is that your regex accepts only *single* arabic character, and doesn't accept spaces.

So instead of `\\p{InARABIC}` you would need something like `[\\p{InARABIC}\\s]+` to

- `\s` let spaces be matched
- `+` match one or more characters.

You may also want to add other characters used in arabic language representing comma, question mark, etc.

Demo:

```
String data = ")أ(\n" +
        ")السلام(\n" +
        "هذا مجرد ) مثال ( .. طبعا";

Pattern Pat = Pattern.compile("\\)([\\p{InARABIC}\\s]+)\\(", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = Pat.matcher(data);
String replacement = m.replaceAll(match -> "(" + match.group(1) + ")");
System.out.println(data);
System.out.println("-----------");
System.out.println(replacement);
```

Output:

```
)أ(
)السلام(
هذا مجرد ) مثال ( .. طبعا
-----------
(أ)
(السلام)
هذا مجرد ( مثال ) .. طبعا
```

---

BUT if your goal is to reverse any `(` and `)` *regardless of their position* then you can use

```
Pat = Pattern.compile("\\(|\\)");
replaced = Pat.matcher(data).replaceAll(match -> {
    if (match.group().equals(")"))
        return "(";
    else
        return ")";
});
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Output:

```
(أ)
(السلام)
هذا مجرد ( مثال ) .. طبعا
```

---

To avoid replacing `(..)..(..)` into `(..(..)..)` you could first let regex match `(..)` to prevent `)` being part of `)..(` match.

Simplified demo:

```
String data = "aa(bb)cc(dd)ee)ff(gg";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(\\w+\\)|\\)(\\w+)\\(", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
String replacement = m.replaceAll(match -> {
    if (match.group(1) == null) {
        return match.group();
    } else {
        return "(" + match.group(1) + ")";
    }
});
System.out.println(data);
System.out.println("-----------");
System.out.println(replacement);
```

Output:

```
aa(bb)cc(dd)ee)ff(gg
-----------
aa(bb)cc(dd)ee(ff)gg
```

Comment: That's the point I don't want to reverse any "(" and ")" only when they are wrong which happens with Arabic text sometimes, even with the Regex you provided I still get no match.
I have even sometimes multiple parentheses which some are good others need to be inverted so the  ++some operations on the extracted text++ part of my code treats different cases

Comment: "even with the Regex you provided I still get no match" since as you see it works on data provided in question problem may be with *how* you are using this regex, or on what *data* it is used. To get better help please provide [mcve] which will let me see case(s) which fails.

Comment: Work as a charm, Thank you @Pshemo, one last question, if I have more advanced ( complicated ) pattern for example : 
Arabic ) text ) arabic ( text ( arabic 
the double reversed parentheses , any idea how to fix them to : 
Arabic ( text ( arabic ) text ) arabic

Comment: I am afraid that would require regex engine which supports recursion, but Java engine doesn't do that. Or write your own state machine (but with that I can't help you).

Comment: Hi @Pshelmo , I was testing the code your provided on other test cases but it gave the following for this text : 
Input : This (is) arabic (text) 
Output : This (is (arabic) text)
it does detect the inner text and the right parentheses and reverses them.
Or nothing has to be done in this case, the parentheses are correct !
Any thoughts ?

Comment: @Slach You could let regex first try to find `(..)` to prevent that `)` be part of `)..(` match. I am thinking about regex like `\(arabic\)|\)(arabic)\(`. With it match of group 1 exists only if it regex matched case `)..(` so only then we should replace it with `(group1)` otherwise we know that it was match of `(..)` so we can replace it with itself - with group0.

Comment: Any idea what should be modified in this [code](https://ideone.com/Jw9x8i) 
https://ideone.com/Jw9x8i in order to replace that functional interface ?( on my local machien works fine , however the server doesn't support functional interface so  I need to re-implement it with no functional interface ) @Pshemo

Comment: @Slach `matcher.replaceAll(replacingWay)` is shorter version of `StringBuffer sb = new StrinbBuffer(); while(matcher.find()){ String replacement = /*here decide what should be replacement for current match*/ matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replacement); } matcher.appendTail(sb); String replacedString = sb.toString();`. Something like https://ideone.com/jkGLQt.

Comment: Actually the server i'm running the code on doesn't support java 9 or + that's why I can't use functional interface , i'll try with the code you provided thanks.